# IP Address change with limited account

Tags: ip-address

Here's what I need to do, any ideas would be helpful.

I need to be able to change the Local IP address of a computer programmatically as a limited user in XP.  Without giving Admin information to the users.  I've played with runas, sanur, and autoit, but all either require giving up the Administrator password or is not extremely reliable.

Again, any ideas would be great.

Answer (score 4):

You should probably create a service that has administrative rights and allow limited users to request an IP change from that service.

Comment: Ha, was just typing the same. :)

Answer (score 1):

Neall is right, you could do this with a service.  You'd need to build & install the service, and create a small client that can be run in limited user mode that would command the service to change the IP.

However, before you go charging down that road, I have to ask: why do you want to change the IP address of the computer?  I'm wondering if you arrived at this as a solution for some other problem that might have a different method of resolution.

Answer (score 0):

I'd imagine you could simply call [LogonUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378184(VS.85).aspx) with admin credentials, and change it from there. That'd require embedding the password in the EXE, of course.